# crosstab and xtabs generates zeros instead of NAs

Tags: r, crosstab, na

I have used the following (sample) data and crosstab() to create a cross-table dataset. When I use this method all the column x row combinations without data becomes zeros in my output dataset. I would like them to be NAs as there are true zero values in the dataset and I cannot distinguish them otherwise.Additionally, I have experimented with xtabs() and get the same problem. Any suggestions for getting the NAs or another method is very much appreciated.

```
WW1_Data <- structure(list(Site_Name = c("Alnön", "Alnön", "Alnön", "Ammarnäs",
"Ammarnäs", "Anjan", "Anjan", "Bäcksand", "Bäcksand", "Fittjebodarna",
"Fittjebodarna", "Flatruet", "Flatruet", "Flatruet", "Flatruet",
"Glen", "Glen", "Glen", "Idre", "Idre"), Year = c("1996", "2000",
"2010", "1996", "2011", "2009", "2010", "2000", "2010", "2008",
"2009", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2008", "2009", "2010",
"1996", "2010"), WW1_Pct_2 = c(0.307692307692308, 0.260869565217391,
0.0833333333333333, 0.75, 0.8, 0.52, 0.5, 0.0833333333333333,
0.375, 0.4, 0.423076923076923, 0.85, 0.483870967741935, 0.56,
0.58, 0.777777777777778, 0.555555555555556, 0.521739130434783,
0.4, 0)), .Names = c("Site_Name", "Year", "WW1_Pct_2"), row.names = c(3L,
4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L,
33L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 59L, 60L), class = "data.frame")

xtabs(WW1_Pct_2 ~ Site_Name + Year, WW1_Data)

## alternatively ##

library(ecodist)
WW1_XTAB  <- data.frame(with(WW1_Data, crosstab(Site_Name, Year, WW1_Pct_2)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the function used when you are aggregating with xtabs is `sum` you can use it with its default setting of na.rm=FALSE by using tapply:

```
> with(WW1_Data, tapply(WW1_Pct_2, list(Site_Name,  Year), sum )  )
                      1996          2000         2008         2009          2010 2011
Alnön         0.3076923077 0.26086956522           NA           NA 0.08333333333   NA
Ammarnäs      0.7500000000            NA           NA           NA            NA 0.80
Anjan                   NA            NA           NA 0.5200000000 0.50000000000   NA
Bäcksand                NA 0.08333333333           NA           NA 0.37500000000   NA
Fittjebodarna           NA            NA 0.4000000000 0.4230769231            NA   NA
Flatruet                NA            NA 0.8500000000 0.4838709677 0.56000000000 0.58
Glen                    NA            NA 0.7777777778 0.5555555556 0.52173913043   NA
Idre          0.4000000000            NA           NA           NA 0.00000000000   NA
```

There is an `as.data.frame` method for tables (which are a special sort of matrix)  which is the object class that `tapply` returns. Your use of `as.data.frame` is superfluous since the result of `reshape` was already a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick. Other solutions welcomed!

```
WW1_XTAB <- as.data.frame(reshape(WW1_Data,idvar="Site_Name",timevar="Year",direction="wide"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(WW1_Data, Site_Name~Year)
```

although this relies on there being only a single entry for each Site/Year combination. If there were more you could use

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(WW1_Data, Site_Name~Year, sum)
```

but this would give 0 rather than NA where there are missing values (on the basis that the sum of a list of zero elements is 0.